# is ther any libpng.dylib available for ubuntu

Tags: shared-library

I have installed libpng on ubuntu but I cannot find the libpng.dylib file that I specifically need. I installed the same library on mac and I have the file. Can somebody tell me why I do  not have this file on Ubuntu?

Comment: *"the libpng.dylib file that I specifically need"* for what, exactly? AFAIK `.dylib` files are OSX dynamic library files, and would not be compatible with Linux. The Linux equivalent would be a `.so` file.

Comment: It is indeed to compile a code that I use on my Mac. I just wanted to try to compile it on a machine running Ubuntu.

Comment: Cross-compile or native compile?

Comment: Excuse me but I do not really understand the question. I am using gfortran for compiling on both OS. I don not think anybody tried before to compile this code on Ubuntu.

Comment: Cross-compile means compile on Ubuntu to run on OSX; native compile means compile on Ubuntu to run on Ubuntu. Regardless, it seems you have an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the question you should really be asking is "How do I compile xxx on Ubuntu?"